# Hiding buttons on a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two `UIButton`s on each `UITableViewCell` and I'm basically trying to set both of the buttons to hide when one or the other is pressed. The only thing I found online are just about using .tag to record a press.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * indentifer = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indentifer forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.random objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIButton * acecept = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    acecept.frame = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x + 200, cell.bounds.origin.y + 20 , 50, 30);
    [acecept setTitle: @"Yes" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [acecept addTarget:self action:@selector(waffles:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    acecept.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:acecept];

    self.deny = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];



    _deny.frame = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x + 250, cell.bounds.origin.y + 20 , 50, 30);
    [_deny setTitle: @"no" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_deny addTarget:self action:@selector(cereal:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    _deny.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_deny];

    UIButton * button = (UIButton *) acecept;
    button.tag = button.tag+1;

    /* if (acecept.hidden) {
     [_deny setHidden:YES];
     } */

    return cell;
}
```

This is how I'm hiding them once they are pressed:

```
-(IBAction) waffles:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"waffles");


    UIButton * button = (UIButton *) sender;
    button.tag = button.tag+1;

    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)button.tag);

    waff = button.tag;


    [sender setHidden:YES];

    if(sender.hidden == YES){
        [self.deny setHidden:YES];
    }

}


-(IBAction)cereal:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"cereal");
    [sender setHidden:YES];
}
```

I've tried multiple `if statements` and tagging the button. I think I need to somehow get the number of the cell view at which one of the button is pressed at, then place that in each `IBAction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made changes in your code..

**Check below code**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString * indentifer = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indentifer forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.random objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIButton * acecept = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    acecept.frame = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x + 200, cell.bounds.origin.y + 20 , 50, 30);
    [acecept setTitle: @"Yes" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [acecept addTarget:self action:@selector(waffles:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    acecept.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    acecept.tag = 1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:acecept];


    UIButton * deny = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    deny.frame = CGRectMake(cell.bounds.origin.x + 250, cell.bounds.origin.y + 20 , 50, 30);
    [deny setTitle: @"no" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [deny addTarget:self action:@selector(cereal:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    deny.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    deny.tag = 2;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_deny];

    return cell;
}

-(IBAction) waffles:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"waffles");

    UIButton *aceceptBtn = (UIButton *) sender;
    [aceceptBtn setHidden:YES];

    UIButton *denyBtn = [aceceptBtn.superview viewWithTag:2];
    [denyBtn setHidden:YES];
}


-(IBAction)cereal:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"cereal");
    UIButton *denyBtn = (UIButton *) sender;
    [denyBtn setHidden:YES];

    UIButton *aceceptBtn = [denyBtn.superview viewWithTag:1];
    [aceceptBtn setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time. your edit works exactly how I wanted it and it works just fine, however theres warnings: incompatible pointer types UIButton *

Comment: accepting your work is with the checkmark right? and sorry i cant give you an up vote... the warnings are at UIButton *denyBtn = [aceceptBtn.superview viewWithTag:2];   and   UIButton *aceceptBtn = [denyBtn.superview viewWithTag:1];

Comment: change your code to UIButton *denyBtn = ( UIButton * ) [aceceptBtn.superview viewWithTag:2]; and UIButton *aceceptBtn = ( UIButton * )[denyBtn.superview viewWithTag:1]; to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

In **.h** declares buttons in this way (with an Outlet)

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonOne;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonTwo;
```

In **.m:**

```
-(IBAction)presentPrincipalViewController:(id)sender {

   [self.buttonOne setHidden:YES];
   [self.buttonTwo setHidden:YES];
}
```

if you want to hide all buttons:

```
-(IBAction)presentPrincipalViewController:(id)sender {

     for (UIButton* someButton in self.view.subviews) {
          [someButton setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time. this was the first thing i tried and the if I click on any of the buttons on any cell, this just caused the last two buttons on the last cellView to disappear then the rest just stayed there and i was unable to press on the rest of the buttons

Comment: Aaaahhhh. Do you have tried to use this?:

`for (UIButton* oneButton in self.view.subviews) {
        [oneButton setHidden:YES];
    }`    (I edit my answer with this code)

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you are using is not right.

You need to create a custom tableview cell with two buttons.

And in that cell's .m class, you can write IBActions for those two buttons.

And in those IBActions, you can hide both the buttons.